# Google Map Projection Skew - Need correct Projection

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, web-mercator

I'm having a really difficult time resolving skewed grids when projecting onto Google maps using Alteryx outputs. Within the module, I'm taking GRD files and aggregating rows and columns to re-size from 30m to 250m grids. Then projecting using EPSG:3857 which I understand to be the correct Web Mercator Aux Sphere for Google/Bing. However, no matter what I research and attempt to implement, I always end up with skew in my squares. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks

[image: Alteryx Process Flow]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to illustrate your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot suggestion. Let me know if any flow item requires explanation.

Comment: In the lower screenshot I see an array of what look like perfect squares. What do you mean by "skew in my squares," then? Are you referring to the one-pixel displacements near some of the crossings? If so, please explain how those squares are represented. What *precisely* are the coordinates of their vertices?